# opendir: Too many open files

Tags: c, linux, file, gnu, opendir

I write this code to print all files in `/home/keep` with absolution path:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void catDIR(const char *re_path);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *top_path = "/home/keep";
    catDIR(top_path);
    return 0;
}

void catDIR(const char *re_path)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct stat file_info;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if ((dp = opendir(re_path)) == NULL)
    {
        perror("opendir");
        return;
    }
    while (entry = readdir(dp))
    {
        if (entry->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;

        //get Absolute path
        char next_path[PATH_MAX];
        strcpy(next_path, re_path);
        strcat(next_path, "/");
        strcat(next_path, entry->d_name);

        lstat(next_path, &file_info);

        if (S_ISDIR(file_info.st_mode))
        {
            catDIR(next_path);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s/%s\n", re_path, entry->d_name);
        }
    }
    free(dp);
    free(entry);
}
```

When I run it.

Not only print some file's path, but also print some error message:

`opendir: Too many open files`

I read `man 3 opendir`, then realize, I had opened too many files.

I do want to know, how to close it? and how to correct this program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably use `closedir` when you finish iterating through a directory's contents.

Also, you might want to read the directory's listing into an array, close the directory, and then recurse on the array. This might help with traversing very deep directory structures.

Answer (score 1):

Run

> cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

what does it give ?
output format is : (number of allocated file handlers) - (number of allocated but unused file handlers) - (maximum number of file handlers)

If you get more number of allocated but unused file handlers, it means that you've to close directories as mentioned by @Matthew Iselin.
You can also change system limit.

More info about changing system limit [Can be found here](http://goo.gl/GU0DA).